# pyspark case statement over window function

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I got a dataframe where I need to check for the below three columns to filter the right rows.

Given Dataframe input:

```
customer_number acct_registration_ts          last_login_ts acct_create_ts
28017150        null                           null         2018-02-13T00:43:26.747+0000
28017150        null                           null         2014-09-11T15:58:29.593+0000
28017150        2014-05-14T23:11:40.167+0000   null         2014-05-12T00:00:00.000+0000
```

Expected Dataframe output:

```
customer_number acct_registration_ts          last_login_ts acct_create_ts
28017150        2014-05-14T23:11:40.167+0000   null         2014-05-12T00:00:00.000+0000
```

Filter condition:

1. If acct_registration_ts is NOT NULL get the max of acct_registration_ts row.
2. If acct_registration_ts is NULL, then check for last_login_ts and if last_login_ts is NOT NULL, then get the max of last_login_ts row.
3. If both acct_registration_ts and last_login_ts are NULL, then get the max of acct_create_ts row.

Here I need to group by customer_number column and then apply the above 3 filter logics. I tried with pyspark window function, but not getting the expected output. Any help would be much appreciated.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a window across all the three columns:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

w = Window.partitionBy('customer_number').orderBy(*[F.desc_nulls_last(c) for c in df.columns[1:]])

df2 = df.withColumn('rn', F.dense_rank().over(w)).filter('rn = 1')

df2.show(truncate=False)
+---------------+----------------------------+-------------+----------------------------+---+
|customer_number|acct_registration_ts        |last_login_ts|acct_create_ts              |rn |
+---------------+----------------------------+-------------+----------------------------+---+
|28017150       |2014-05-14T23:11:40.167+0000|null         |2014-05-12T00:00:00.000+0000|1  |
+---------------+----------------------------+-------------+----------------------------+---+
```